# Modern C++ wrapper around C Dirent.h

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

I am trying to write a modern c++ wrapper around the c header, dirent.h.

To read the contents of a directory in C, something like the following is written:

```
int listdir(const char *path) {
  struct dirent *entry;
  DIR *dp;

  dp = opendir(path);
  if (dp == NULL) {
    perror("opendir");
    return -1;
  }

  while((entry = readdir(dp)))
    puts(entry->d_name);

  closedir(dp);
  return 0;
}
```

Converting this to modern c++, I have the following (where m_dir and m_dirent are `std::unique_ptr`'s, and m_files is a `std::vector<string>`)

```
filesystem::Directory::Directory(std::string dir) : m_dir(opendir(dir.c_str()), closedir),
                                                  m_dirent(new struct dirent())
{
    //If the directory can not be read, throw an error.
    if (!m_dir) {
        sdl2::SDLFileSystemRead_Failure ex;
        throw ex;
    }

    while (&(*m_dirent = *readdir(&*m_dir)))
    {

        m_files.emplace_back(std::string(m_dirent->d_name));

    }

}
```

This only half works. When I wrote it, I was oblivious that I was just checking to see if the address of the expression `*m_dirent = *readdir(&*m_dir)` existed(which, of course it does!). 
According to [The Single UNIX ® Specification, Version 2](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/readdir.html), readdir(DIR*) returns a null pointer if it has read the last file and there are no more files to be read. However, I am uncertain on how to keep setting the dirent pointer to whatever the dir pointer is reading without calling `.reset()` on `m_dirent`. Doing this just results in garbage data being read, though, since I assume the file pointer is lost when `dirent` is destroyed.

How can I convert this

```
  while((entry = readdir(dp)))
    puts(entry->d_name);
```

into modern C++?

Comment: In general, the underlying issue is that you're attempting to do a line-by-line translation from C to C++.  That is not the best way to turn a non-OO, `C` based API into a C++ interface.  You have to look at the overall design, and apply the appropriate pattern(s) to it.  For an example, look at how `boost` implements the filesystem API.

Comment: Have a look at Boost.FileSystem (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/) which has been accepted into Technical Report 2.

Comment: If you have access to Koenig's [Ruminations on C++](http://www.amazon.com/Ruminations-Decade-Programming-Insight-Experience/dp/0201423391), he has an example of this in one of his chapters.  However, that might not count as Modern C++ since it pre-dates the standard by a year or so, so it doesn't have all the experience since then to build on.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I wasn't aware that Koenig had something on directories in there. Do you recall how it was exposed? In particular, did Koenig expose the directory as an iterator?

Comment: @DietmarKühl: I'll need to look at the code again.  IIRC, there was discussion about making it an iterator, but not code that actually did so.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this count's as *modern* as I posted something like this in UseNet in the previous millennium ([here](http://free-cad.sourceforge.net/SrcDocu/d9/d0f/directory_8h_source.html) is a refined version). It evolved slightly to become one of the first components which were used to seed [Boost](http://boost.org) in 1998. Thanks to the work of others it got further developed at Boost and eventually turned into the [file system library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) which formed the basis of the [File System TS](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n3940.html).

However, it all started with a simple idea: how to expose `opendir()`, `readdir()`, and `closedir()` nicely? The somewhat obvious answer is: using an iterator! Here is a simple version and demo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <memory>
#include <dirent.h>

class dir_it
    : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, std::string>
{
    std::shared_ptr<DIR> dir;
    std::string          current;
    void advance() {
        dirent  entry;
        dirent* result;
        if (!readdir_r(dir.get(), &entry, &result) && result) {
            this->current = result->d_name;
        }
        else {
            this->dir.reset();
        }
    }
public:
    dir_it(std::string const& path)
        : dir(opendir(path.c_str()), [](DIR* dir){ dir && closedir(dir); }) {
        if (!dir) {
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to open directory '" + path + "'");
        }
        this->advance();
    }
    dir_it(): dir() {}

    std::string const& operator*() const { return this->current; }
    dir_it&            operator++() { this->advance(); return *this; }
    dir_it             operator++(int) {
        dir_it rc(*this);
        this->operator++();
        return rc;
    }
    bool operator==(dir_it const& other) const {
        return bool(this->dir) == bool(other.dir);
    }
    bool operator!=(dir_it const& other) const {
        return !(*this == other);
    }
};

int main() {
    std::copy(dir_it("."), dir_it(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Of course, the file system library in Boost and in the File System TS are **much** more capable than this somewhat naive implementation. If your implementation ships with an implementation of the TS I'd use that. If it doesn't you might want to consider Boost's implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Comma operator to the rescue !

```
while(entry.reset(readdir(m_dir.get())), entry)
    puts(entry->d_name);
```

Although, as the comments say, this is not a fantastic API for a filesystem. Iterators that transparently adapt an underlying directory would be cool, for example.